# What are the effects of consuming haram food ignorantly?

Tags: food, halal-haram, imaan, mistake

lately there is a serious issue of haram meat being labeled as halal and it has been consumed by muslims unknowingly. I read somewhere that any food that is haram or its source is from haram source will render it to become part of the flesh of the person who ate and will weaken his iman. Is this correct? Pls advice preferably with hadiths to deny or support. Jazakillah

Comment: If you read something somewhere you should share the source.

Answer (score 1):

If you consume haraam food knowingly, then it is a sin and will cause your *dua to be rejected*, apart from **in the case of necessity where the person wouldn't survive if they didn't consume it (i.e. during a war/conflict, or due to the worldly pandemic we are in now [i.e. limited places open and unavailability of food], starvation, weakness, insanity etc) in that case if a person was to consume it if there isn't ANY halal food available anywhere at all that is in reach of them then it is not a sin upon that person so long as they do it as a means of survival, not desiring it or gaining pleasure from it and as soon as halal food becomes available they stop consuming that which is haraam, even if it means spitting it out of their mouth. The same ruling would apply to eating/drinking in a restaurant etc that serves alcohol, a off-license etc, if for instance the person was about to faint as they are passing that restaurant/shop and there's no food/drink available elsewhere and no other way of helping this situation then out of pure necessity they could purchase from there just the amount of food they need to stop them from feeling faint, neither enjoying it or overindulging in it (the alcohol itself is still forbidden though)**.

*The Prophet (s.a.w) said "Allaah is good and does not accept anything but that which is good. Allaah has enjoined upon the believers that which He enjoined upon the Messengers." Allah says (interpretation of the meaning): "O you who believe (in the Oneness of Allaah — Islamic Monotheism)! Eat of the lawful things that We have provided you with, and be grateful to Allaah” [al-Baqarah 2:172]*

*And He says (interpretation of the meaning): “O (you) Messengers! Eat of the Tayyibaat [all kinds of Halaal (lawful) foods which Allaah has made lawful (meat of slaughtered eatable animals, milk products, fats, vegetables, fruits)] and do righteous deeds” [al-Mu’minoon 21:51]*

*Then the Prophet Muhammad (s.a.w) mentioned a man who travels a great deal and becomes disheveled and covered with dust, who raises his hands to the heavens (and says), 'O Lord, O Lord,' when his food is haram, his drink is haram, his clothes are haram and he has been nourished with haram, so how can he receive a response? [40 Hadith Nawawi 10; Muslim]*

*Meaning it's unlikely his dua will be answered. However his salahs (which includes dua etc) will still be accepted from that person in the sense that it serves to fulfill his obligations without the need for repeating it.*

**To consume haraam where it's absolutely necessary to do so: [translation of the meaning] '...But as for him who is forced by severe hunger, with no inclination to sin such can eat these above mentioned meats), then surely, Allaah is Oft-Forgiving, Most Merciful' [Al-Maa'idah 5:3]**

**[translation of the meaning] “And why should you not eat of that (meat) on which Allaah’s Name has been pronounced (at the time of slaughtering the animal), while He has explained to you in detail what is forbidden to you, except under compulsion of necessity?” [al-An’am 6:119]**

**More details of the rulings of necessity can be found on this link:
https://islamqa.info/en/answers/130815/permissibility-of-haraam-things-in-the-case-of-necessity-and-the-conditions-governing-that**

Now, in regards to the consumption of haraam food being consumed unknowingly, then there is no sin whatsoever upon that individual although it is preferred, but not obligatory, to bring the food back up.

It is mentioned in Sahih Al Bukhari that "Saaiduna Abu Bakr had a slave who used to give him some of his earnings. Saaiduna Abu Bakr used to eat from it. One day he brought something and Saaiduna Abu Bakr ate from it. The slave said to him, " do you know what this is?" Saaiduna Abu Bakr then enquired, "What is it?". The slave said "once, in the pre-islamic period of ignorance I foretold somebody's future though I did not know this knowledge of foretelling but I cheated him, and when he met me, he gave me something for that service, and that is what you have eaten from." Then Saaiduna Abu Bakr put his hand in his mouth and vomited whatever was present in his stomach" (Mazahirul Haqq p.450 v.3)

Now, in regards to it lowering the imaan of that individual; that would be the case of any disobedience done towards Allah anyway, although we should still hold on to hope and never give up on His mercy, asking for His forgiveness and repenting to Him regularly whilst correcting ourselves. Then our imaan should, in shaa Allah, increase again. So long as we don't prescribe any partner to Allah which if we were to die in such a state we would never get forgiven for; we also need to protect ourselves from major hypocrisy, as it's kafir.

The Imam of the Ahlus-Sunnah Ahmad ibn Hanbal, may Allah have mercy upon him, was asked as to whether iman increases and decreases. He replied: "It increases until it reaches the highest part of the seventh heaven, and it decreases until it reaches the lowest part of the seventh plane." He also used to say: "Iman is speech and action. It increases and decreases. If you perform good deeds, it increases, and if you do wrong, it decreases."

And Allah knows best

Answer (score -1):

> What are the effects of consuming haram food ignorantly?

I conjecture that it can have its negative material/spiritual effect on the human, albeit it might not be considered as a sin if the person have done its necessary research of its halal ... I speculate so,